# How to have the list of the url failures?

Tags: wget

I try to download all the URL from a specific file : file.csv in order to do that I use this command line :  `wget -c -i file.csv`
But I would like to get a list of all the URL that wget was not able to download.

When I use this kind of command line : `wget -c -i file.csv 1>output_file.txt 2>error_file.txt`
I got a error_file.txt with to many information and a lot of those information are useless for instance, the URL already downloaded are mentionned in this file (it is not a failure case).

Best,

Comment: Use it like this: `wget -c -i file.csv --rejected-log=logfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that command this way:

```
wget -c --rejected-log=/path/to/logfile -i file.csv
```

- `--rejected-log=logfile`:

  ```
  Logs all URL rejections to logfile as comma separated values. The values include the reason of rejection, the URL and the parent URL it was
  found in.
  ```

**Note:** You need to create a log file for use and give the path in that command

See: `man wget`

Comment: When I try to use : 'wget -c --rejected-log=logfile -i test.csv' with the test.csv that contain only one url line : 
 https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Wesleyan%20English%20Chapel.%20Lisburne%20Mines%2C%20Cardiganshire%2C%20Built%252.jpeg
The jpeg in this url is not found as expected but no logfile is created at all. Do you know why ?

Comment: The `logfile` has to exist! Create one say `mylogs.txt`, then add it to the line: `wget -c --rejected-log=/path/to/mylogs.txt -i file.csv `

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me. I have added a flag for failed logfile named failed.csv, have created it in the same location, but 400 bad request, 404 errored links are not added to it. Using Wget v1.21.3.